# Nested RecyclerViews in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, parallax, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a problem with a `View` hierarchy in the app I am working on right now.

One of the screens looks like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar/>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView>
        ... items, some of which are horizontal Recyclers...
    </RecyclerView>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The whole idea is to have the `Toolbar` parallax nicely when scrolling down the `RecyclerView` content.

The whole thing works rather nicely, but there is a problem with the mentioned parallax behavior (which is done with a custom `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` implementation).

There are two cases, depending on what item user focuses when scrolling:

1. If a normal child is focused, the whole thing works as expected - `Toolbar` parallaxes in and out.
2. If a Recycler-based child is focused, the content `RecyclerView` will scroll as expected, but the parallax behavior will not fire, leaving the layout in a weird mid-state.

Any idea why this is happening and how to get the correct behavior, aka the events being passed all the way up to the `CoordinatorLayout`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each of your sub-recyclerView's, you need to call

```
setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

on that RecyclerView (you can do this from whatever viewholder you are using for your main recyclerview to create the sub ones). This is a currently known bug in nested scrolling. If I were to guess, I would say that it probably has something to do with the fact that nested scrolling layouts are not supposed to send nested scrolling notifiers to parents if they are scrolled in directions in which they do not have a scrolling axis, if that makes any sense.